# How to chain JavaScript to when hovering element to change picture of an element and display block third element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to make something like a slider; I have 4 buttons which when pressed I want to change the main picture and show the content for each picture. After a bit of browsing and testing I managed the get the image to change on hover however I am having difficulty getting the content div to change. I was trying to use the display none for the other content divs and block for the active one however I can't chain the whole thing; the best I could do was this:

```
    $('#changeImage').attr('src', 'pic1.png');
  },
       function() {
    $(".content.one").css("display", "block");
   },
        function() {
    $(".content.two").css("display", "none");
   },
        function() {
    $(".content.three").css("display", "none");
   },
        function() {
    $(".content.four").css("display", "none");
   }
)
```

However only the `.content.one` changes and only when I move my mouse out. I hope I made my self clear. If I can help clarify anything feel free to ask.

Here is the whole JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li:nth-child(1)").hover(
  function () {     
    $('#changeImage').attr('src', 'pic1.png');
  },
       function() {
    $(".content.one").css("display", "block");
   },
        function() {
    $(".content.two").css("display", "none");
   },
        function() {
    $(".content.three").css("display", "none");
   },
        function() {
    $(".content.four").css("display", "none");
   }
);

$("ul li:nth-child(2)").hover(
  function () {     
    $('#changeImage').attr('src', 'pic2.png');
  }
);

$("ul li:nth-child(3)").hover(
  function () {     
    $('#changeImage').attr('src', 'pic3.png');
  }
);

$("ul li:nth-child(4)").hover(
  function () {     
    $('#changeImage').attr('src', 'pic4.png');
  },
     function() {
    $(".content.one").css("display", "none");
   },
        function() {
    $(".content.two").css("display", "none");
   },
        function() {
    $(".content.three").css("display", "none");
   },
        function() {
    $(".content.four").css("display", "block");
   }
);

});
</script>
```

and the whole html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<img src="clear.png">
<ul id="side-bar">
<li class="one"><a href="#"><img src="1-1.png"
onmouseover="this.src='1-2.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='1-1.png'"></a></li>
<li class="two"><a href="#"><img src="2-2.png"></a></li>
<li class="three"><a href="#"><img src="3-1.png"
onmouseover="this.src='3-2.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='3-1.png'"></a></li>
<li class="four"><a href="#"><img src="4-1.png"
onmouseover="this.src='4-2.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='4-1.png'"></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="image"><img id="changeImage" src="pic1.png"></div>
<div id="content-wrapper"><img src="content.png"></div>
<div class="content one"><p>content 1</p><a href="#" class="more">read more...</a></div>

<div class="content two"><p>content 2</p><a href="#" class="more">read more...</a></div>

<div class="content three"><p>content 3</p><a href="#" class="more">read more...</a></div>

<div class="content four"><p>content 4</p><a href="#" class="more">read more...</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using .hover() incorrectly. Hover takes **two** functions as parameters: the function to execute on mouseover and the function to execute on mouseout. For example:

```
$(function() {

    $('#my-id').hover(

        // mouse over
        function() {
            $('#foo').show();
            $('#bar').addClass('baz');
        },

        // mouse out
        function() {
            $('#foo').hide();
            $('#bar').removeClass('baz');
        });
});
```

In your code you are passing **four** functions as parameters to the hover call bound to the element "ul li:nth-child(1)". In all of your other hover event handlers you are only passing **one** function.

Comment: very helpful answer i was indeed using .hover() incorrectly i didn't know it took two functions as parameters for over and out when i change my  when i replaced .hover() with .mouseover() everything works like a charm :)